# Can't write file into directory created by me

Tags: flutter

I am trying to write files into a folder which I am creating just before writing files. Everything seems fine in debug console. It seems files are writed but when i go to device's file manager, nothing shows up in downloads folder. I couldn't figure it out.

My code to write file:

```
  void saveEachPointInSeparateFiles(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM');
    final String formattedDateTime = formatter.format(now);

    final path = await downloadsPath;
    print("Downloads path: $path");

    final directory = Directory("$path/$formattedDateTime");
    try {
      directory.create();
      print(
          "Directory created : $directory\nDirectory path: ${directory.path}");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Cant create directory error: $e");
    }
    // find all different points respect to indoorLevel,
    // and write them to the storage as separate files.
    context.read<ResultsCubit>().filteredData.forEach((key, value) {
      value.forEach((key, value) {
        _addJsonFile(
            folderPath: directory.path,
            model:
                PointBeaconDataModel(pointModel: key, beaconDataList: value));
      });
    });

    emitShowFiles();
  }

  void _addJsonFile({
    required PointBeaconDataModel model,
    required String folderPath,
  }) async {
    String point =
        "${model.pointModel.lat.toStringAsFixed(6)}_${model.pointModel.long.toStringAsFixed(6)}";
    var file = File('/$folderPath/$point.json');
    print("FILE PATH: $file.path");

    var json = model.toJson();
    //print("JSON !!!! : $json ");

    try {
      file.writeAsString(json);
      print("FILE writed to this directory: ${file.path}");
      jsonFiles.add(file);
      emitShowFiles();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error occured: $e");
    }
  }

  void emitShowFiles() {
    emit(ShowFiles(files: jsonFiles));
  }
```

And the debug console output:

```
I/flutter ( 5977): Permission Granted
I/flutter ( 5977): Downloads path: /storage/emulated/0/Download
I/flutter ( 5977): Directory created : Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/16-03'
I/flutter ( 5977): Directory path: /storage/emulated/0/Download/16-03
I/flutter ( 5977): FILE PATH: File: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/16-03/36.898414_30.647404.json'.path
I/flutter ( 5977): FILE writed to this directory: /storage/emulated/0/Download/16-03/36.898414_30.647404.json
W/DartWorker( 5977): type=1400 audit(0.0:3320705): avc: granted { read write } for name="36.898414_30.647404.json" dev="sdcardfs" ino=435696 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c215,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file
```

By the way, I am using a pyhsical Android device which I was be able to write files into Download folders. I am just unable to do this if I create new folder

Answer (score -2):

Usually this problem occurs in Emulator.

Try it on a real device.

Comment: This is a comment at best. At the very least try to explain why it could be an emulator problem.

Comment: I am using a pyhsical android device. Not an emulator